# Apply a mask to multiple images(for same geo location) in a image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, masking, data-collection

I have a image collection which holds multiple images of the same area. I can apply mask individually to those images but how do I apply a mask to all the images in the collection. Say the mask i have to apply is to filter out all the pixels with value more than a given value. Since i have multiple images for the same location, I want to 'and' the logic so that i get a single image with pixels displayed which satisfy the condition for all the images. Here is some code i wrote which works for fine when i have single image:

```js
    Map.setOptions('SATELLITE')
    var image = ee.ImageCollection("imagesForIrvineCalifornia");


    var min = image.aggregate_min('min');
    var max = image.aggregate_max('max');


    var VIS_OPTIONS = {
      'b1': {
        description: 'b1' +
                     'b1 descripion',
        visParams1: {min:min.getInfo(), max:max.getInfo(), palette: ['DCF5E9', 'BDDEC9', '9DC7AA', '82B38E','689E75', '4E8A5B', '387847'], bands: ['b1']}
      }
    };

    var maskingFunc = function(val){
      return function(i){
        var band = i.select('b1');
        var mask = band.lte(val);
        return i.updateMask(mask);
      }
    }

    var maskedImage = image;
    var cutoffVal=3000 ;
    maskedImage = image.map(maskingFunc(cutoffVal));

    Map.addLayer(maskedImage.select('b1'), VIS_OPTIONS['b1'].visParams1, '(b1)', true);
    Map.centerObject(Map.layers().get(0).get('eeObject'));
```

Comment: I have the code ready to give you a mask with pixels that fulfill the condition in all images (*0: at least 1 pixels does not fulfill, 1: all pixels fulfill*), but how are you planning to get 1 value out of many images? a mean value? or you want one image with as many bands as images in the collection?

Comment: Thanks. I do not want the values from individual images in this case, just the visualization showing which areas satisfy the condition in all the images from the image collection.

Answer (score 0):

As I don't have your image collection, I tested it with a fantasy collection made of randomly generated images. Worked for me.

**EDIT**: This code only works when images inside the collection are overlapped.

```js
Map.setOptions('SATELLITE')
var image = ee.ImageCollection("imagesForIrvineCalifornia");

var min = image.aggregate_min('min');
var max = image.aggregate_max('max');


var VIS_OPTIONS = {
  'b1': {
    description: 'b1' +
                 'b1 descripion',
    visParams1: {min:min.getInfo(), max:max.getInfo(), palette: ['DCF5E9', 'BDDEC9', '9DC7AA', '82B38E','689E75', '4E8A5B', '387847'], bands: ['b1']}
  }
};

var maskingFunc = function(collection, val, band){
  // convert col to list
  var collist = collection.toList(collection.size())
  // get first img of collection and compute condition
  var ini = ee.Image(collist.get(0)).lte(val)
  // get collection without first image
  var rest = ee.ImageCollection(collist.slice(1))

  // function to iterate over the 'rest' collection to 'and' logic
  var wrap = function(i, first){
    var f = ee.Image(first).select(band)
    var image = i.select(band);
    var mask = image.lte(val);
    return mask.and(f)
  }

  // iterate over the collection and return a single image
  return ee.Image(collection.iterate(wrap, ini))
}

var cutoffVal = 3000;
var maskedImage = maskingFunc(image, cutoffVal, 'b1');

Map.addLayer(maskedImage.select('b1'), {min:0, max:1}, '(b1)', true);
Map.centerObject(Map.layers().get(0).get('eeObject'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Rodrigo. I will test soon and Mark it as accepted soon.

Comment: I tested it. Unfortunately it did not work for me. Do not know what i am missing here.

Comment: @umbersar, this is how I tested it: https://code.earthengine.google.com/7df2fa0bb768f8c4169043daa9835348 but I think I know the error. I left your VIS_OPTIONS which makes no sense because what you want (and get with the code) is a binary mask (0 or 1). I changed the code, see what happens now.

Comment: Thanks for your help but the script is not working. I do not see anything on the map.

Comment: You've have to share your imagecollection then. Have you seen the code of the link?

Comment: yes, I did see the code. Unfortunately due to restrictions on data, I can't share the image collection. Apologies.

Comment: @umbersar, how is your data different from the fantasy data I used? (apart of having different values in every pixel) What's the issue/error when you do what I proposed?

Comment: Hi Rodrigo, here is the script: https://code.earthengine.google.com/959f95de42449616348bb35a3ba1a42f